# Why different outputs in presenting time by these two ways in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display the same time with `$time` and javascript time

Code

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$current = strtotime($today);
$final = date("d/Y/m", strtotime("-2 month", $current));
echo $final.'<br />';
echo $today.'<br />';
echo $time;
?>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

where they display different time

```
22/2015/03

2015-05-22

02:56:22

Fri May 22 2015 10:56:22 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

I am referring to the different time and is using my `http://localhost`.
Why did the two times differ?

Comment: Why what is happening? You are spitting out the date in 3 different ways.

Comment: Are you asking why the time is different or why the format is different?

Comment: One time is UTC, the other is your local time. What's the problem?

Comment: When you ask a server what time it is, it will check the local time for that server. Your php is run from a web server that could be in a different country meaning it will return the local time for that country... *(Unless you tell it otherwise)*

Comment: I Am reffering to time and is using my localhost

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to clearly point out this is being run locally (on localhost) it saves all the questions and people can get on with helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily the answer would simply be the fact that PHP is server side and JS is client side and both time zones differ usually but you mentioned this is on your `localhost` so the explanation of this difference lies in the fact that there is a default timezone saved for your PHP configuration which is not same as your own timezone. You can verify this by using

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)**

When you run that code you will see that the timezone PHP tells you is not the timezone on your client. You can match the two however using **[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)** amongst other methods.

Comment: You're maybe right about the php.ini but even though i've changed it it didn't change the time.. however i've come up with changing the time value instead. Anyways thanks a lot. 
    `$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime("+8 hour",strtotime(date('H:i:s'))));`

Comment: Did you restart your web server after changing the timezone in PHP.ini?

Comment: yup i did. and still the same. maybe some bugs occurs or what ever. this is how i set timezone - date.timezone = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"

Comment: Try with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

The date function of PHP formats a date/time.  Date() is a JavaScript object.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

The PHP date will reflect that of the server, the JavaScript date will reflect that of the client/browser.

The locale may also vary and affect presentation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale

Comment: i am using my http://localhost and is using an older version of php (php 5.2.6) as for my pc is still xp.. thanks a lot.. hehehe

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to consider here.

1.Php return time where it is executed or the time according to the timezone if it is used with date functions it means you can play with php date functions and get time as per your requirement.

2.but in case of javascript you always get your localmachine time unless you are using `getTimezoneOffset`

now coming to your requirement if you want same time to be appended in `demo` div you can use php date function along with javascript

so it could be done like

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<?php echo date("m d y");?>';
</script>
```

or use variable you already have for date and time